# Knit to flexdashboard issue

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I am trying to "knit to flex_dashboard" the following code in RStudio. I am giving a link because pasting it directly here is causing formatting problems.

https://github.com/futdevseige/R-code/blob/main/Code.rmd

Now, when I try to use the "knit to flex_dashboard" function in RStudio, it is giving me the following error:
[image]

I updated r version using the console, but that didn't fix it. RStudio is also up to date.

Comment: Hm. Except for the part involving your dataset (which I could not test) your Rmd renders fine on my machine.

Comment: @stefan Oh it started working. I actually didn't notice the r version of mine was latest :P Thanx for help :)